What is the difference between estimating parameters via MLE versus minimizing deviations from expectation?
What is the difference between estimating parameters using MLE (or MAP with uniform priors):
$$\theta^* = \arg \max_\theta p(X|\theta)$$
and estimating them according to which setting would engender the smallest deviation between our measured data and our expectation conditional on those parameters? That is,
$$\theta^* = \arg \min_\theta ||\,\bar{X} - \mathbb E_{p(X|\theta)}[X|\theta]\,||.$$
Here's an example. I have a coin that is possibly biased ($\theta = p(H) \in \lbrace{0.25, 0.50, 0.75\rbrace}$), but you don't know which one). I flip it $1000$ times and see $625$ heads. We want to estimate $\theta$.
Alice says, "Well, the probability of seeing $625$ heads is $3.8 \times 10^{-138}, 0.5 \times 10^{-19}$, and $7.4 \times 10^{-19}$ for $\theta = \lbrace{0.25, 0.50, 0.75\rbrace}$ respectively. $\theta = 0.75$ maximizes the likelihood $\mathscr L = p(X|\theta)$ given by binomial probability, so that's my guess."
Bob says, "If $\theta$ were $\theta = \lbrace{0.25, 0.50, 0.75\rbrace}$, then we'd see $250$, $500$, and $750$ heads in expectation respectively. $0.5$ and $0.75$ minimize the deviation of what we saw from expected results, so I'm indifferent between these as my guesses."
Is there a name for Bob's style of parameter estimation? Is there a problem with his approach? Does it have any statistical guarantees? Of course, one can think of his algorithm as optimization against a loss function $L = (\bar{X} - \mathbb E_{\mathscr L}[X|\theta])^2$ but I wonder if it is a sensible approach that has an intuitive probabilistic formulation (like there is with MSE loss and Gaussian likelihood in OLS).

What norm does "$||\quad ||$" specify?  How would you apply this approach to a problem with more than one parameter, where generically your minimization problem only determines a single real value, assuming "$\bar X$" is intended to be the mean of the data?

Minimizing a distance between observations and estimates occurs with methods like least squares method or least absolute deviations

@whuber I wasn't sure if I should specify it since there may be [conventional] norms with sensible interpretations and others without and I didn't want to assume too much. In practice with something like this, you'd probably want L2 norm (see the last paragraph). And I think Bob's approach generalizes to the multivariate case all the same, as long as the likelihood represents a multivariate density? You might have nonuniqueness of solutions, but that's the case in this univariate example as well.

It is still not very clear how the multivariate case would work. The reason is because you are using the mean. But what mean are you gonna use instead?

In typical problems it is possible to make $\bar{X} = E[X|\theta]$ and the loss can go to zero. In that case we sprak about the method of moments. In your example you have a parameter space that can capture all possibleoments in the data.

@SextusEmpiricus Forgive me if I'm missing something. Can we not let $\bar{X}$ be the empirical mean of the data, i.e. the component-wise mean? And then $E[X|\theta]$ is the expectation with respect to $\mathscr L$, where again sums of vectors (to compute the expectation) are component-wise and $\mathscr L$ itself is a joint distribution over the components of $\theta = {\theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_n}$? How exactly does Bob's method become ill-defined for higher dimensional cases?

@actinidia how does it work for a linear regression where we have data points $x_i$ measured under different conditions $y_i$. What sort of average or averages do you use?

@SextusEmpiricus I think I see what you're getting at. My question's inspired by situations where the params are the only inputs into a data-generating process, while linear regression involves params and auxiliary inputs. Bob's approach can be adapted to LR, though: for each point $x_i$, the likelihood given $\beta$ is normal around $x_i \beta$ and so the expectation is $x_i \beta$. Take this vector of expectations for every $x_i$ as $\mathbb E[X|\theta] \in \mathbb R^n$, subtract it from $\bar{X} = {y_1, ..., y_n} \in \mathbb R^n$, and take the norm as $L$ to be minimized w.r.t. $\beta$.
